# Update firebase data in async loop

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I create a todolist with repetitive tasks (for example, every monday I would like to display the same todos). I use firebase to store my datas, for example :

**description:** "test"
**jour:** "Sunday"
**priorite:** 2
**statut:** true
**titre:** "Bonjour"

My code works but I would like create a condition "if the day ('jour') in firebase is different of the current day then all the status ('statut') are updated to false (Except those of the current day)".

It's possible ?

This is my HTML code :

```
    <ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="primary">
    <ion-title>Todolist</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons end>
      <button ion-button icon-only (click)="addItem()">
        <ion-icon name="add-circle"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content class="background">

  <ion-list no-lines>
    <ion-row *ngFor="let item of items | async; let last = last; let index = index;">
      <ion-item-sliding class="m-5" #slidingItem *ngIf="(item.jour) === (theDate | date :'EEEE')" [ngClass]="{'bg-green' : (item.priorite == 1),'bg-orange': (item.priorite == 2),'bg-red': (item.priorite == 3)}">
        <ion-item [ngClass]="{'bg-green' : (item.priorite == 1),'bg-orange': (item.priorite == 2),'bg-red': (item.priorite == 3)}">
          <ion-checkbox color="primary"
                        [(ngModel)]="item.checked"
                        (ngModelChange)="updateItem(item.$key,check.value)"
                        #check></ion-checkbox>
          <ion-item text-wrap item-left
                    (click)="viewItem(item)"
                    [ngClass]="{'bg-green' : (item.priorite == 1),'bg-orange': (item.priorite == 2),'bg-red': (item.priorite == 3), 'barre-texte': (item.checked == true)}">
            {{item.titre}}
          </ion-item>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item-options>
          <button ion-button color="danger" (click)="deleteItem(item.$key)">Supprimer</button>
        </ion-item-options>
      </ion-item-sliding>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

Typescript :

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {ModalController, NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {AddItemPage} from '../add-item/add-item'
import {ItemDetailPage} from '../item-detail/item-detail';
import {Data} from '../../providers/data';

import {AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable} from 'angularfire2/database';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  items: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
  public theDate = Date.now();

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public modalCtrl: ModalController, public dataService: Data, db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.items = db.list('/todolist');
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {}

  // Méthode angularfire2
  updateItem(key: string, newText: any) {
    this.items.update(key, {statut: newText});
  }

  resetStatut(key: string, statut: boolean) {
    this.items.update(key, { statut: statut });
  }

  addItem() {
    let addModal = this.modalCtrl.create(AddItemPage);
    addModal.onDidDismiss((item) => {
      if (item) {
        this.saveItem(item);
      }
    });
    addModal.present();
  }

  saveItem(item) {
    this.items.push(item);
    this.dataService.save(this.items);
  }

  deleteItem(key: string)  {
    this.items.remove(key);
  }

  viewItem(item) {
    this.navCtrl.push(ItemDetailPage, {
      item: item
    });
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: And you want to handle this logic in firebase ? If I were you, I would check the day in Angular, and make the correct request. Because assuming you have 1 billion users, it's better to make **their** computer work, rather than your server.

Comment: You have right, but it's possible ?

Comment: Of course it's possible ! You should take a look at [MomentJS](https://momentjs.com/) if you want to work with dates (et si je ne me trompe pas et que tu es français, momentJS permet de mettre en forme les dates dans notre langue, ce qui s'avère même très pratique)

Comment: Ah d'accord merci :) . Et la condition doit être faite dans le typescript ou dans le html ? Parce que quand je fais un *ngIf="(item.jour) === (theDate | date :'EEEE'); else resetStatut(item.$key, false)" ça plante

Comment: Moi perso je mettrais la condition dans le constructeur, ou dans le ngOnInit. Du coup, ton application charge, elle détermine le jour, et elle dit au service "tiens, on est mardi, envoie moi les tâches de mardi". Du coup tu prends que les données de mardi, et tu te débarrasses de 6 jours inutiles ! Tu vois ce que je veux dire ?

Comment: Oui je vois ce que tu veux dire, ça me paraît être une bonne façon de faire, maintenant il ne reste plus qu'à appliquer ^^"

Comment: Bonne chance :D

Answer (score 0):

on ionViewDidLoad() method you need to load items and compare date, I strongly recommend use moment() when you need to use dates.

some like that:

```
this.items.array.forEach(element: Task => {
  //compare each element
  if(element.jour != moment.day()) {
    this.update(element);
  }
});
```

hope to help

Comment: Thanks, but why ionViewDidLoad() instead of the constructor or ngOnInit ?

Comment: Because I think you need to reload every time to page was loaded, if you put on constructor only load when the page is created.